# for validator in validators: TypeError: 'Length' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i am facing this error making the form validation

for validator in validators:
TypeError: 'Length' object is not iterable

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Length

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
       username=StringField(label='User Name',validators=Length(2,30))
       email_address=StringField(label='E-mail')
       password1=PasswordField(label='Password')
       password2=PasswordField(label='Confirm Password')
       submit=SubmitField(label='Create Account')
```

here is the complete error log

> C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy_*init*_.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
> warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\navee\Desktop\sikander\Coding\Python\Flaskmarket\run.py", line 1, in 
> from market import app
> File "C:\Users\navee\Desktop\sikander\Coding\Python\Flaskmarket\market_*init*_.py", line 9, in 
> from market import routes
> File "C:\Users\navee\Desktop\sikander\Coding\Python\Flaskmarket\market\routes.py", line 4, in 
> from market.forms import RegisterForm
> File "C:\Users\navee\Desktop\sikander\Coding\Python\Flaskmarket\market\forms.py", line 5, in 
> class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
> File "C:\Users\navee\Desktop\sikander\Coding\Python\Flaskmarket\market\forms.py", line 6, in RegisterForm
> username=StringField(label='User Name',validators=Length(2,30))
> File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 33, in **new**
> return UnboundField(cls, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 384, in **init**
> self.field_class.check_validators(validators)
> File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 177, in check_validators
> for validator in validators:
> TypeError: 'Length' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTForms expects `validators` to be a list (thus the plural), so it can iterate over it. Your code should be:

```
username=StringField(label='User Name',validators=[Length(2,30)])
```